# Error implementing custom SPfx App

Tags: solution-package, sharepoint-framework, packaging, gulp

I have a problem implementing my share-point SPfx app to the share-point site of my organisation.

I followed the instructions provided by microsoft at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn yet when I add my App to the sharepoint I get an implementation error.

This is the message I get: [image: My sharepoint website is in Dutch]
Headers translated from dutch to english from left to right:

**Enabled, Valid app-package, Implemented, Error message with App-package**

Any Idea what could be going wrong?

The step I used to create my .sppkg file were:

1. `gulp bundle --ship`
2. `gulp package-solution --ship`
3. Then I uploaded the .sppkg to the App Catalog and I get the error

The other thing I noticed is when I run a development build by neglecting `--ship` from the `build` and `package-solution` I get no error. So I think there might be something wrongly configured in the SharePoint site or I am configuring my application the wrong way.

If anymore information is need please let me know how to resolve this error "3cd06c9e-6015-6000-b78b-ead6a160cb77"

Comment: can you go to `config > package-solution.json` file and then increase the version number to `1.0.0.1` and upload the app again and check ?

Comment: I did as you ask by increasing the version number and reproducing the build steps I defined in my post but I still get the Error message with the package.

Comment: are there any errors in gulp serve ? Also, try the below steps `1) gulp clean 2) gulp build 3) gulp bundle --ship 4) gulp package-solution --ship`

Comment: After looking a bit further I noticed I was now able to add the custom app on a modern page. But I get a SPLoaderError. It seems to be looking for the en-US version of the Strings file, yet in my source-code I have put in a nl-nl.js file so it will look for the dutch version of strings. Yet it tries to load the en-US version.

Comment: Error: ` [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
Laden van onderdeel da1dd1e0-1015-4823-8c58-bb82fd0eb852 (KwaliteitWebPart) is mislukt.
Oorspronkelijke fout: Laden van URL https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/<website>/sites/appcatalogus/ClientSideAssets/f089e819-e482-474c-bba6-451f5d838aa9/kwaliteitsmodule-kwaliteitwebpartstrings_en-us_cd3656878d0ed9ba474cea0a7e144b9f.js`

Comment: Any advice on how to properly configure my app to use the `nl-nl.js` version of strings instead of `en-us.js`. Thanks for you help so far man! Really great.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue related to webpart localization.

In your `nl-nl.js` file, ensure that you have added the entries that exactly match the `mystrings.d.ts` interface entries.

Also, to debug your code, you can change the file `./config/write-manifests.json` to:

```
{
 "cdnBasePath": "<!-- PATH TO CDN -->",
 "debugLocale": "nl-nl"
}
```

The MS official documentation provides a great reference to implement localization.

Reference - [Localize SharePoint Framework client-side web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts)

Please implement the necessary changes as mentioned in the above link. SharePoint  will automatically show the localized values based on the currentUICulture value.

Comment: Thank you, I will be reading trough the documentation, I will update as i go.